# Turn event into a async call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm wrapping a library for my own use. To get a certain property I need to wait for an event. I'm trying to wrap that into an async call.

Basically, I want to turn

```
void Prepare()
{
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.Initialized += OnFooInit;
    foo.Start();
}
string Bar
{
    return foo.Bar;  // Only available after OnFooInit has been called.
}
```

Into this

```
async string GetBarAsync()
{
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.Initialized += OnFooInit;
    foo.Start();
    // Wait for OnFooInit to be called and run, but don't know how
    return foo.Bar;
}
```

How could this best be accomplished? I could just loop and wait, but I'm trying to find a better way such as using Monitor.Pulse(), AutoResetEvent or something else.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thats where TaskCompletionSource comes into play. There is little room for the new async keyword here. Example:

```
Task<string> GetBarAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> resultCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    foo = new Foo();
    foo.Initialized += OnFooInit;
    foo.Initialized += delegate
    {
        resultCompletionSource.SetResult(foo.Bar);
    };
    foo.Start();

    return resultCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Sample use (with fancy async)

```
async void PrintBar()
{
    // we can use await here since bar returns a Task of string
    string bar = await GetBarAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(bar);
}
```

Comment: I guess this function could be wrapped in a async function? Or just add async to the function and return resultCompletionSource.Task.Result; which would cause it to wait?

Comment: this can be wrapped in an async function, updating the sample now

Comment: Just noticed, System.Threading.Tasks isn't available on Windows Phone 7 which is my target platform. Is there an alternative? (have found [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks) but I'd like to minimize dependencies)

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I'm using the library you found for this same scenario and can't get the task to wait for the event to return. Maybe this is a bug in the library.

Comment: I never tried, since I didn't want to depend on more libs. Posted [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484130/turn-event-into-a-async-blocking-call-on-windows-phone-7-c) highlighting this.

Comment: `foo` will disappear from scope before it invokes its Initialized event. You may be OK but there's a danger that `foo` will have been garbage collected. To keep it alive you can pass it into the TaskCompletionSource constructor as state.