# Turn event into a async/blocking call on Windows Phone 7 (C#)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

(I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963301/turn-event-into-a-async-call-c) earlier, but had forgotten to mention some constraints. This is for Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) with Silverlight 4 and C# 4, which lacks `System.Threading.Tasks`, `await` and more. I'm asking again in hope for a native solution without 3rd party libs like [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks).)

I'm wrapping a library for my own use. To get a certain property I need to wait for an event, which fires pretty quick. I'm trying to wrap that into a blocking call.

Basically, I want to turn

```
void Prepare()
{
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.Initialized += OnFooInit;
    foo.Start();
}
string Bar
{
    return foo.Bar;  // Only available after OnFooInit has been called.
}
```

Into this

```
string GetBarWithWait()
{
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.Initialized += OnFooInit;
    foo.Start();
    // Wait for OnFooInit to be called and run, but don't know how
    return foo.Bar;
}
```

How could this best be accomplished?

Comment: You can now download `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` for Windows Phone 7 - it allows async and await usage as you would expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string GetBarWithWait()
{
    foo = new Foo();

    using (var mutex = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        foo.Initialized += (sender, e) => 
        {
            try
            {
                OnFooInit(sender, e);
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.Set();
            }
        }

        foo.Start();

        mutex.WaitOne();
    }

    return foo.Bar;
}
```

But you have to be absolutely certain that Foo will call the `Initialized` event no matter what happens. Otherwise, you'll block the thread forever. If Foo has some kind of error event handler, subscribe to it to avoid blocking your thread:

```
string GetBarWithWait()
{
    foo = new Foo();

    using (var mutex = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        foo.Error += (sender, e) => 
        {
            // Whatever you want to do when an error happens
            // Then unblock the thread
            mutex.Set();
        }

        foo.Initialized += (sender, e) => 
        {
            try
            {
                OnFooInit(sender, e);
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.Set();
            }
        }

        foo.Start();

        mutex.WaitOne();
    }

    return foo.Bar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! I'll wait a bit more before marking as answer.

Comment: One note, ReSharper says "Access to disposed closure" inside `finally { mutex.Set(); }`. Is it wrong or..?

Comment: The mutex is disposed when leaving the `using` block. Therefore, if the `Initialized` event of Foo is called after leaving the `GetBarWithWait` method then it will throw an exception. If you know that it won't happen, you can safely ignore this warning.