# "Async All the Way Down": Well, what's all the way at the bottom?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to fully understand `async`-`await` and one of the gaps in my understanding is seeing what is "All the Way Down." I create an `async` method, it is called by another `async` method, etc., all the way down to something that I understand in vague terms like "a UI" or "a web server that can handle multiple requests". How would I describe in technical terms what is "all the way down"?

So let's take the second example of a web server. Say I have a controller action like

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRecords()
{
    var records = await repository.GetRecordsFromDbAsync();
    return Ok(records);
}
```

Where can I find in the .NET source code the "all the way down" code that enables this to be called asynchronously?

Comment: Here's an example "one step below" async: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9963301/87698

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every procedural programming language is a series of function / procedure calls, with one function / procedure calling another. It is possible to represent this sequence of calls from procedure to procedure using a call graph [see Wikipedida for a starting point for call graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph). These graphs generally show the sequence of procedural calls starting at the top and proceeding to the bottom.

I quickly produced a diagram of a partial call graph for an ASP .NET MVC application. The diagram is only a partial representation for an ASP .NET MVC application because it omits things such as the initial receipt of the request by the operating system (eg. Windows), web server (eg. IIS) and various components of ASP .NET that are responsible for processing a HTTP request as it travels through the ASP .NET Request processing pipeline.   These matters can can be omitted for the purposes of this discussion. Although it's worthwhile noting that they would sit at the top of the call graph, because they deal with the initial stages of handling the HTTP request, and ultimately, at some point ASP .NET ultimately invokes an action of a controller.

As you can see in the diagram I've represented the action of the controller that would be invoked by ASP .NET as an async action. On the left hand side of the call graph is a series of async procedure calls. Ultimately it arrives at the box that is the subject of your question.

The answer to the question that is consistent with the notion "All the way down" is that "I am an async method". What does this async method do? Well, that depends on what you want to do? If you're reading or writing a file then it's an async call to read or write a file. Are you making a database query? Then the call is to an async method that makes that query. With this in mind I guess you can say that often what is at the bottom will be a device driver method, that performs an IO access asynchronously. Although it could easily be a long running compute bound asynchronous operation that you wish to perform such as processing an image, or video file.

It's worthwhile noting the right hand side of the call graph here too. Although often you may want to call async methods all the way down, the right hand branch of this call graph shows that you don't necessarily need to call an async method at the bottom at all. 
[image]

Answer (score 18):

The phrase "async all the way down" is a bit misleading, because it usually refers to the fact that once you use an async method, you need to have async methods all the way *up* (or *back*, depending on your mental image) - from your async method to its *caller*, and then your caller's caller, and so forth, all the way back.

Your example shows a WebApi/MVC controller that exposes an `async` task. The next step in the `async` chain is the WebApi/MVC infrastructure that receives the HTTP GET request, maps it to a controller, and dispatches the call to the controller's method. This infrastructure is `async` aware, meaning it knows to call `async` controller methods properly and `await` their result to return the HTTP response.

As to how exactly that infrastructure is implemented, I don't specifically know, nor care - I know that ASP.NET web services support `async Task` controllers, and that's good enough for me.

Comment: I'd say the wording of the phrase is based on "it's turtles all the way down", since it supports a similar analogy.

Comment: True, that's why it's confusing.

Comment: You answer is misleading - you should care how infrastructure is implemented. It's one of the largest caveats of async code, IMO. It should be, "async all the way down *and* up". The reason is that *blocking code in async methods will block execution of the current context* [see also here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Allowing async operations to block the execution thread defies the idea of async i/o and means that whatever performance increase you hope to gain, it'll only be due to use of multiple threads, which means none for single-threaded applications.

Comment: I should care about the infrastructure as far as its contracts and promises go. Knowing how the internals are implemented is instructive and can aid debugging, but as far as async/await is concerned, knowing my framework supports async Task entry points means I can use async Task entry points.

Answer (score 15):

All the way down would be the Win32 API. At that level, async I/O is done via `OVERLAPPED` objects, and alertable waits such as `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

Comment: Do you have any links you could provide? If so, I will likely choose as best answer.

Comment: @user7127000 here is nice blog post about the subject:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 6):

`GetRecordsFromDbAsync` is an async method, so your top level async method (which is called by the async-supporting ASP.NET web server) just hands over its asyncness to the next level.

All the way down until `GetRecordsFromDbAsync` or its descendants actually calls the last async method in the call stack. There it presumably becomes native and will it register an I/O interrupt or something else which gets called when the file is read, the web request is handled, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear from your question where you found that quotation, or in what context it is being used. However, "async all the way down" is generally understood to mean that you shouldn't switch back and forth between synchronous and asynchronous methods in a single logical operation.

If something is to be done asynchronously, it should be *consistently* asynchronous, at all levels—thus, "all the way down" (and up) the hierarchy/call stack/etc. In other words, it never makes sense to do a synchronous, blocking call at any point in asynchronous code, because then it isn't really asynchronous at all.

From the .NET Parallel Programming team's blog entry, ["Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/):

> **Async All the Way Down**
>
> The point here is that you need to be extremely careful when wrapping asynchronous APIs as synchronous ones, as if you’re not careful, you could run into real problems. If you ever find yourself thinking you need to call an asynchronous method from something that’s expecting a synchronous invocation (e.g. you’re implementing an interface which has a synchronous method on it, but in order to implement that interface you need to use functionality that’s only exposed asynchronously), first make sure it’s truly, truly necessary; while it may seem more expedient to wrap “sync over async” rather than to re-plumb this or that code path to be asynchronous from top to bottom, the refactoring is often the better long-term solution if it’s possible.

As for your question about where can this be found in the .NET source code, [MSalters has already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41438797/366904). Fundamentally, the .NET APIs will call down to system-level APIs provided by the Windows operating system. These perform asynchronous I/O, and signal the caller when they have completed. You don't really need to understand how this works on a technical level, though; that is the whole point of the abstraction.

Comment: The link you provided was useful. As to where the "async all the way down" came from I suspect it came from an article written by Stephen Cleary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx which I came across a long time ago.

Comment: Ah, that is also a very nice link, @Darren. Why isn't it included in your answer? :-)

Comment: because I found Uncle Bob's drawing of a call graph on a blackboard more useful for understanding what was meant in Cleary's article.